# Is it bad practice to use C-like static variables in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, static, singleton, class-variables

All I want to do is make a utility class for my (stream capture) app that grabs settings from my website. I want to call it from other files as a simple `[RemoteConfig updateSettings];`

**My goal is to use this remote configuration utility without making an object for every situation where I grab remote settings.**

The information around static/class variables and methods in Objective C is hazy and very opinionated, so after a lot of experimenting, I got this to work. But it looks funny, which makes me think something is incorrect.

**RemoteConfig.h** simply declares the **+(void) updateSettings** method.

This is my **RemoteConfig.m**:

```
#import "RemoteConfig.h"

static NSMutableData* _configData;
static NSString* url = @"http://local.namehidden.com:90/json.html";
static int try;

@implementation RemoteConfig

+(void) updateSettings
{
    NSString *identifier = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];

    //Create URL request
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]
                                                           cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                                       timeoutInterval: 10];

    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"id=%@", identifier];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLConnection* connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request
                                                                delegate:self];
    [connection start];
}

///////////////////////////// DELEGATE METHODS ///////////////////////////////////

+(void)connection:(NSConnection*)conn didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse*)response
{
       if (_configData == NULL) {
        _configData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    }
    [_configData setLength:0];
    NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse: responseData length:(%d)", _configData.length);
}

/// and so on...
```

It looks funky, putting C-style variables above the @interface/@implementation. A lot of people say try to use properties, some say do the static method singleton trick, I've seen a little library that handles singletons but this was the simplest solution I found.

My questions-

- Is this proverbially bad?
- What limitations does this have?
- What are the alternatives, and what is best?

Comment: Not "proverbially bad", but ugly and thread-unsafe.

Comment: I figured it would cause a mess with threads. What has similar effect but ensures thread safety?

Comment: I guess no simple concept can ensure thread safety in itself, it's rather that it's not possible or very hard to build thread safe code with global variables.

Comment: @H2CO3 well, C++'s `thread_local` can be combined with `static` if you *really* care.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII C++ suggestions are always welcome, I'm not a C++ expert (albeit I should be one perhaps).

Comment: @H2CO3 I just tried it - Apple's build of clang doesn't support `thread_local` yet. Hopefully we'll get that feature soon though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this proverbially bad? What limitations does this have?

Global variables tend to impose a certain set of restrictions:

- they often don't clean up their resources properly
- are not thread safe (e.g. can be used from one thread or may introduce state per thread)
- they may not necessarily be safe to nest
- they can combat some of these problems by serializing requests -- introducing excessive suspension and locking.
- they become very difficult to 'extend' safely (i.e. adding global variables makes it more fragile)
- they are hard to test, and can lead to bugs which are very difficult to reproduce

> What are the alternatives, and what is best?

Just move those variables to ivars, and create instances of the class rather than relying on global state. Then you can extend and abstract in a way which will not affect your clients significantly.

Note that `static NSString* const url = @"http://local.namehidden.com:90/json.html";` would not be a mutable variable (added `const`). So it's only `_configData` and `try` which would need to be ivars.

Comment: But the whole point of this is to make a utility that doesn't require instantiation of a new object every time I want to just grab settings from a JSON interface.

Comment: Don't be afraid of the objects. Or, use a singleton.

Comment: @user creating an objc object is trivial in the great majority of contexts, e.g. many are objects are created and destroyed when manipulating strings and creating collections types. if you want to minimize network requests, then you can pass around one object which has successfully made the request. some people don't mind working with globals -- some find them a pain. i've been writing objc for 10 years. i assure you real programs can be developed without introducing global variables or singletons (they do exist in the frameworks). personally, i find it much easier that way.

Comment: Wain, what is your recommended way of implementing a singleton in Objective-C?

Answer (score 0):

Using static variables like this is no less safe than using a Singleton. You will still have the same issues with thread safety e.g. A Singleton is of course easier to Mock so that might be a benefit with Singleton's.

In both cases you are introducing global mutable state (global immutable state is unproblematic). How problematic this is depends on where in the call hierarchy these variables exist. If most of your code is built on top of some functions which change their output based on some global mutable state then that makes it hard to test and analyse your code.

So if you do introduce global mutable state, try to either:

1. Place it has high as possible in your layering. Meaning as little as possible other code should depend on this code.
2. Make sure state changes don't change the output of functions using it. E.g. global mutable state which is just caching might work.
3. If total code of your program is small you could use global state as there is little difference between global variables in a 500 line program and member variables in a 500 line class.